# Update batch documents if exist else insert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have set of documents in array, Which is working fine if I use with `insertMany` query. Now, I want to add condition in query, If the document exist with same **product_ID** update it. How to use array of documents with `updateMany`. I don't want to use update one by one.

**Array of Documents:** `First time Insert`

```
[
{_id:"5ea0428e5f725d00079afaab", product_id:345, title:"Car"},
{_id:"5e40428e5f725d00079afa4b", product_id:456, title:"Ball"},
{_id:"5e60428e5f725d00079afaab", product_id:555, title:"Dog"},
]
```

**Expected Code like that:** `Second time update` because `product_id` already exist.

```
  return db.collection("cars").updateMany([
    {_id:"5ea0428e5f725d00079afaab", product_id:345, title:"Hen"},
    {_id:"5e40428e5f725d00079afa4b", product_id:456, title:"Cow"},
    {_id:"5e60428e5f725d00079afaab", product_id:555, title:"Goat"},
    ]).then((items) => { 
    return { statusCode: 200, body: items }; })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('=> an error occurred: ', err);
      return { statusCode: 500, body: 'error' };
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.map()` your array into an array of [replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#replaceone) operations and use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db-collection-bulkwrite) to execute them. Note that you're passing `_id` which has to be unique anyway:

```js
var data = [
{_id:"5ea0428e5f725d00079afaab", product_id:345, title:"Car"},
{_id:"5e40428e5f725d00079afa4b", product_id:456, title:"Ball"},
{_id:"5e60428e5f725d00079afaab", product_id:555, title:"Dog"},
];

var upserts = data.map(doc => ({
    "replaceOne": {
        filter: { product_id: doc.product_id} ,
        replacement: doc,
        upsert: true
    }
}));

console.log(upserts);
```

```
db.collection.bulkWrite(upserts)
```

Comment: There is an error: bulkWrite only supports insertOne, insertMany, updateOne, updateMany, removeOne, removeMany, deleteOne, deleteMany